# How to check if type from assembly is ComVisible

Tags: c#, .net, com, interop, com-interop

I'm writing an add-in manager for Enterprise Architect.

When loading an assembly (addin dll) I need to know which of the types defined in the assembly is COM visible, so I can add the required registry keys to register it for COM interop.

Here's what I have have so far:

```
public EAAddin(string fileName):base()
{
    //load the dll
    this.addinDLL = Assembly.LoadFrom(fileName);
    //register the COM visible classes
    this.registerClasses(this.addinDLL);
    //load referenced dll's
    foreach (AssemblyName reference in this.addinDLL.GetReferencedAssemblies())
    {
          if (System.IO.File.Exists(
                 System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(this.addinDLL.Location) + 
                    @"\" + reference.Name + ".dll"))
          {
            Assembly referencedAssembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(this.addinDLL.Location) + @"\" + reference.Name + ".dll");
            //register the COM visible classes for the registered assembly
            this.registerClasses(referencedAssembly);
// ... more code ...
private void registerClasses (Assembly assembly)
{
    foreach (Type type in assembly.GetExportedTypes()) 
    {
            register(type, assembly);
    }
}

private void register(Type type, Assembly assembly)
{
    var attributes = type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ComVisibleAttribute),false);
    if  (attributes.Length > 0)
    {
        ComVisibleAttribute comvisible = (ComVisibleAttribute)attributes[0];
        if (comvisible.Value == true)
        {
            //TODO add registry keys here
        }
    }            
}
```

This doesn't work as type doesn't seem to contain a ComVisibleAttribute.

Anyone know how to figure out which of the ExportedTypes in an Assembly are COM visible?

Comment: By default, public types are COM visible.  If the assembly has `ComVisible(false)`, then only the `ComVisible(true)` public types are COM visible.

Comment: @PauloMadeira Thx Paulo, I'm aware of that rule, but how can I figure out which type in an assembly has `ComVisible(true)` or `ComVisible(false)` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to the comment from Paulo I was able to figure it out.
The type only has a ComVisibleAttribute if it is different from the Assembly default.

So this operation (called on one of the types returned `Assembly.GetExportedTypes()`) by seems to do the trick

```
/// <summary>
/// Check if the given type is ComVisible
/// </summary>
/// <param name="type">the type to check</param>
/// <returns>whether or not the given type is ComVisible</returns>
private bool isComVisible(Type type)
{
    bool comVisible = true;
    //first check if the type has ComVisible defined for itself
    var typeAttributes = type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ComVisibleAttribute),false);
    if  (typeAttributes.Length > 0)
    {
         comVisible = ((ComVisibleAttribute)typeAttributes[0]).Value;
    }
    else
    {
        //no specific ComVisible attribute defined, return the default for the assembly
        var assemblyAttributes = type.Assembly.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ComVisibleAttribute),false);
        if  (assemblyAttributes.Length > 0)
        {
             comVisible = ((ComVisibleAttribute)assemblyAttributes[0]).Value;
        }
    }
    return comVisible;
}
```

Comment: Very helpful.  I used this method in the C# Interactive window to find what options I had for a COM object.  I just had to add the using for ComVisibleAttribute first ("using System.Runtime.InteropServices;").

Comment: Thanks, @GreetBellekens. That was very useful.